# Batch remove parenthesis from file name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename, batch-processing

After successfully removing a bunch of Google Drive Folder duplicates, some files retain a "filename(2)"name.

Is there a way to batch rename every file so the parenthesis and the number inside the parenthesis is gone?

That includes folders and sub-folders.

Comment: I've done this before, when I was testing 'owncloud' but, it's a pain since you can't use `for` loops with parenthesis.  As PA asked above, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create `renfiles.bat.txt` for you to examine in Notepad and then rename to `.bat` and execute if you are happy with it.

```
@echo off
dir /b /a-d *(*).* |find /i /v "%~nx0" |find /i /v "repl.bat" |repl "(.*)\(.*\)(\..*)" "ren \q$&\q \q$1$2\q" xa >"renfiles.bat.txt"
```

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

**Edit:** This version will recurse through subdirectories:

```
@echo off
dir /b /s /a-d *(*).* |find /i /v "%~nx0" |find /i /v "repl.bat" |repl ".*\\(.*)\(.*\)(\..*)" "ren \q$&\q \q$1$2\q" xa >"renfiles.bat.txt"
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement it to sub-folders as well?
Thank you!

Comment: Superb! Thanks a bunch. It's quite elegant how it displays the results ☺

Comment: In case your dropbox link disappears, here's the official thread of the repl.bat script for anyone who stumbles across in the future:
http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855:::

Comment: @GabrielMeono There is an official thread at SO too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir

Answer (score 3):

Try like this :

Create a file test.bat with the code below in it and replace the path to test in the var `$path`

```
@echo off 
set $path="C:\Users\CN Micros\Desktop\PROGRAMMATION\test"
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=^(^)" %%a in ('dir /b/a-d %$path%') do (
if exist %$path%\"%%a(%%b)%%c" echo ren %$path%\"%%a(%%b)%%c" "%%a%%c"
)
pause
```

Then run it in the CMD or by double clicking.
If the output is ok for you remove the `echo`

The program create 3 tokens : `%%a` = what's before the (), `%%b` What's inside the () and `%%c` what's after the ().

Then we arrange this 3 tokens to rename the files without the ().

If you have some file who have the same final name ie : `"file(1)name"`, `"file(2)name"` --> `"filename"`
It will work only with the first one. If you have this case you have to add a counter at the end of file to be sure that they will be renamed.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. How do you run this code? I tried to run it through CMD and as a bat without results. I have low experience coding.

Comment: Please supply an explanation of the code in your answer, this will help future readers.

Comment: old bump, sorry, but how would one go about the case of removing a preceding space in the case of "My File (1).jpg" to prevent a space preceding the extension?

Comment: with a string substitution : `set "file=My File(1).jpg"` and then `set "file=%file: =%"`

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /s /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 SET "name=%%~na" 
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 SET "newname=!name:)=!"
 SET "newname=!newname:(=!"
 IF "!name!" neq "!newname!" (
  IF EXIST "%%~dpa!newname!%%~xa" (ECHO cannot RENAME %%a
   ) ELSE (ECHO(REN "%%a" "!newname!%%~xa")
 )
 endlocal
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You'd need to set your required directory into `sourcedir`. I used `u:\sourcedir` which suits my testing.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.